# Format no such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, fmt

I was trying to use the C++ format utility (std::format). I tried to compile this simple program:

```cpp
#include <format>

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::format("{}, {}", "Hello world", 123) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

When I try compiling with `g++ -std=c++2a format_test.cpp`, it gives me this:

```c
format_test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: format: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <format>
      |
```

I have got GCC 10.2.0

Comment: That's a C++20 thing. Do you have the newest GCC?

Comment: @tadman i'm from 2023 with gcc 11.3.0 and still cant include <format> with -std=c++20 nor c++2a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, `std::format` is now supported in `gcc 13.1` version!
https://godbolt.org/z/TW9G8Gh5Y

Answer (score 15):

According to this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support there are currently no compilers that support "Text formatting" ([P0645R10](https://wg21.link/P0645R10), `std::format`). (As of December 2020)

The feature test macro defined by that paper is `__cpp_lib_format`  (also listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test)), so you can write your code like this to check:

```cpp
#if __has_include(<format>)
#include <format>
#endif

#ifdef __cpp_lib_format
// Code with std::format
#else
// Code without std::format, or just #error if you only
// want to support compilers and standard libraries with std::format
#endif
```

---

The proposal also links to https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt as a full implementation, with `fmt::format` instead of `std::format`. Though you have to jump through some hoops to link the dependency or add it to your build system and to deal with the license / acknowledgement if necessary.

Your example with `{fmt}`: https://godbolt.org/z/Ycd7K5

Comment: It's 2022 and this still hasn't been implemented?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: If it hasn't been implemented, then why is it mentioned in books and references? I was reading about this library on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format. Even if I'm running the example code snippet, I got the same error as above. I'm quiet confused why a feature that hasn't been implemented yet is mentioned a lot in documents.

Comment: @Avinash Probably because the literature is ahead of actual development. The standards committee publish their standards documents first, then the literature is written and compiler development on those new features starts. This would be my guess as to what has happened

Comment: @Avinash You are reading the standard. The C++ 20 std says "std::format" should act and behave like so and so. But the standard has no say over if and when compiler devs will implement the said standard.

Answer (score 13):

[Text formating](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) [P0645R10](https://wg21.link/P0645R10) is implemented in

- GCC libstdc++ 13
- Clang libc++ 14 (but marked as incomplete)
- MSVC STL 19.29 (VS 2019 16.10)

[Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: I'm having this error but in `VS 2022 17.8.5`